# How can i present a view controller inside a particular area?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationViewController`, so when I execute this code

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

I get the `DetailViewController` on the whole screen (`frame(0, 0, 320, 480)`), so what I needed is to push a `ViewController` but in a specific view/area, for example I want to push the `DetailViewController` in `frame(0, 44, 320, 372)`, what I basically have is a scrollView  for swiping viewControllers, & from inside that specific view controller I want to push a second view controller without destroying the toolbar.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use ChildViewController's

Comment: Container view controller http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html